# Intuition for the bias of the partial sums of the Liouville function

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, riemann-hypothesis

It's a well known result that the Dirichlet series of the Liouville function $ \lambda(n) $ is given by

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda(k)}{k^s} = \frac{\zeta(2s)}{\zeta(s)} $$

If we use Perron's formula on this, we get some expression like

$$ L(x) = \sum_{k \leq x} \lambda(k) = \frac{x^{1/2}}{\zeta(1/2)} + \sum_{\rho} \frac{x^\rho}{\rho} \frac{\zeta(2 \rho)}{\zeta'(\rho)} + O(1) $$

where the sum runs over the nontrivial zeroes (of multiplicity one) of the Riemann zeta function. Since $ \zeta(1/2) = -1.46 \ldots $, if we assume the Riemann hypothesis this suggests that the function $ L $ should have a bias to be negative, and this is indeed true: it's the subject of the [Polya conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_conjecture), for instance. Moreover, the first term of this expression also predicts the magnitude of the bias quite well: just to give an example, $ L(10^4) = -94 $, and based just on the first term of the above expression we would predict it's around $ -100/1.46 \approx -68 $, which is not far off from the actual value.

My question is this: often we can get "elementary intuition" into the behavior of these kinds of sums by pseudorandomness heuristics, appropriately modified. For example, the Riemann hypothesis is (roughly) equivalent to the central limit theorem bound on the function $ L(x) $. Is there such an intuition for why the partial sums of the Liouville function would be predominantly negative? Any intuition would probably have to contrast the Liouville function with the Mobius function, since the absence of the $ \zeta(2s) $ on the numerator from the Dirichlet series of $ \mu(k) $ means that the partial sums of the Mobius function show no such bias to be negative.

I would be happy with any answer which doesn't appeal to some analytic number theoretic machinery: Perron's formula, Mellin transforms, *et cetera*. Ideally I'm looking for something of the form "there are slightly more primes that are $ 3 \pmod{4} $ than primes $ 1 \pmod{4} $ because the congruence class $ 1 \pmod{4} $ has all of the odd squares in it".

**Edit:** There has been [another question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33246/heuristic-reason-for-polyas-conjecture?noredirect=1&lq=1) on this subject a decade ago, but it got no answer of the nature I'm looking for here.

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question of mine from a decade ago: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33246/heuristic-reason-for-polyas-conjecture

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heuristic reason for Polya's conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33246/heuristic-reason-for-polyas-conjecture)

Comment: @PeterHumphries I saw your question before asking mine, but your question didn't get any answer of the kind I wanted: the only answer is just saying "if we use Perron's formula and assume the zeroes are behaving nicely, then the bias coming from the pole at $ s = 1/2 $ survives". I agree it's kind of a duplicate otherwise.

Comment: We have $\sum_{k \leq x } \lambda(k) = \sum_{k\leq x} \mu(k) \left\lfloor \sqrt{ \frac{x}{k}} \right\rfloor $, and removing the floor function (i.e. assuming the fractional part is uncorrelated with $\mu(k)$ ) gives $ \sqrt{x} \sum_{k\leq x} \frac{\mu(k)}{ \sqrt{k}} $ which is a partial sum of the zeta function. So there might not be a solution without discussing the zeta function.

Comment: @WillSawin I'm not sure what you mean by "which is a partial sum of the zeta function". I agree that there is likely going to be an obstacle to finding a solution without discussing the zeta function, mostly due to the appearance of $ \zeta(1/2) $ in the bias term. 

If the value appearing was within the domain of absolute convergence (so to the right of the line $ \Re(s) = 1 $), I could imagine some arguments which mess around with the Euler product could possibly recover this factor, but as it stands I have no clue how an elementary method would give $ \zeta(1/2) $.

Comment: $\sum_{k\leq x} \frac{\mu(k)}{\sqrt{k}}$ is a partial sum of the series $\sum_{k} \frac{\mu(k)}{\sqrt{k}}$, which formally evaluates to $\zeta(1/2)^{-1}$, and I think the partial sums converge to $\zeta(1/2)^{-1}$ if RH is true.

Comment: @WillSawin Ah, I see what you mean.

Comment: @WillSawin $\sum \mu(n)/n^s$ does not converge at $s = 1/2$, or in fact anywhere on ${\rm Re}(s) = 1/2$: if it converged at a point on that line then $\sum \mu(n)/n^s = 1/\zeta(s)$ for ${\rm Re}(s) > 1/2$ and we know $1/\zeta(s)$ has poles on the line ${\rm Re}(s) = 1/2$. When a Dirichlet series $\sum a_n/n^s$ converges on a half-plane ${\rm Re}(s) > \sigma_0$ and has a meromorphic continuation to some line segment on ${\rm Re}(s) = \sigma_0$ that includes a pole, it doesn't converge anywhere on that line. This also explains why $\sum 1/n^s$ doesn't converge anywhere on ${\rm Re}(s)=1$.

Comment: An analogue for power series is that if $\sum a_nz^n$ converges on $|z| < R$ and has a meromorphic continuation to some arc on $|z| = R$ that includes a pole, it does not converge anywhere on $|z| = R$.  It is essential in these statements that the singularity is a pole. If it were a logarithmic singularity then you can have convergence on the boundary. For instance, $\sum z^n/n$ converges on $|z| = 1$ for $z \not= 1$ and $\sum 1/p^s$ converges on ${\rm Re}(s) = 1$ for $s \not= 1$: these have logarithmic singularities at $z = 1$ and $s = 1$.

Comment: A proof of this result in the case of power series is at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4451799/a-power-series-with-poles-on-its-convergence-circumference (Note: I am not "Conrad" there.)