# Curious about a question on zeta zeros?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, nt.number-theory

I have Edwards and Titmarsch books on Riemann zeta function with me. I could not find (maybe I did not read through that carefully), but are there results similar to the form like the one given below:

> Is there a non-trivial zero $\rho$ starting from which $(\Im(\rho)\log(2)/2\pi )$ runs only through integer values

I would love any elaboration or links on this topic.

Thanks,
Roupam Ghosh

Comment: I can't imagine that the imaginary parts of the roots are integral multiples of, what, $$ \frac{2 \pi}{\log 2} $$ down the road. I think there is no mention because it is not plausible.

Comment: Can you make a look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32324/ ? As far as I understand the "real" conjecture is that the imaginary parts of the zeros are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$...

Comment: Dear Author, I don't wish to make you sceptical about Splotchy's answer below, as it makes use of a plausible conjecture to show that yours is false. Even more, if you assume implicitly in your question that the real parts of zeros are $1/2$, then the answer is unconditional. I would suggest in the future to cite the conjectures more accurate: if I were Edwards or Titmarsch, I would be offended by attributing of such expectations to myself.

Comment: This question could have been resolved with a quick look at the Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function

Comment: Scott, many questions can be resolved in exactly the same way. Your criteria to judge whether a question is trivial or not are completely mysterious. 

Comment: A very interesting  question would have been whether the  Riemann zeta function have an infinite  number of zeros which lies inside a vertical arithmetic progression ? 
ini
There is a result due to putnam which says "infinite number of elements of any AP wont be zero's of the zeta function.

On the non-periodicity of the zeros of the Riemann zeta-function. 
Amer. J. Math. 76, (1954). 97–99. http://www.jstor.org/stable/2372402?origin=crossref 



Comment: In this article, van Frankenhuijsen, Machiel Arithmetic progressions of zeros of the Riemann zeta function. J. Number Theory 115 (2005), no. 2, 360–370. the authors give a bound on the maximum possible length of arithmetic progressions of zeros of the Riemann zeta function ζ(s). 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such a conjecture is false.

EDIT: A simpler argument - a more precise asymptotic for the number of
zeroes $N(t)$ of imaginary part $\le t$ (counted with multiplicity)  is
$$N(t) = \frac{t}{ \pi} \log \frac{t}{2 \pi e} + o(\log t),$$
This is enough to show that, for any fixed $\epsilon > 0$,
$$N(t + \epsilon) - N(t) \sim \frac{\epsilon}{\pi} \log t,$$
and thus, for sufficiently large $t$, and for any interval of length
$\epsilon$, there are zeroes (whose imaginary part lies) in  this interval,
which also implies the conjecture is false. THIS DOES NOT USE GRH.

PS: Scott Carnahan helpfully remarks that the wikipedia article points out that Littlewood noticed that the difference in the imaginary parts of the zeros tends to zero as $t 
\rightarrow \infty$ (presumably by exactly using this asymptotic result of von Mangoldt above). Personally I prefer mathematics rather than an appeal to authority, but apparently that is not enough for some.

REMARK: Dear Wadim, please read this again, and realize that it DOESN'T USE GRH. The estimate of zeros (which was basically known by Riemann) is about zeroes in the CRITICAL STRIP (real part in $[0,1]$) not the CRITICAL LINE. Having done this, you can delete all your comments, I'll edit this answer, and we can all pretend it never happened. (In fact, I'll make this community wiki so you can delete this remark yourself.)

Comment: Splotchy, you miss the point: the conjecture from OP is about 1/2+in\alpha$ for *some* $n\in\mathbb Z$, not all $n\ge n_0$.

Comment: One can obviously choose a set $S\subset\mathbb Z$ such that $\{1/2+in\alpha:n\in S\}$ satisfies both Riemann's, Montgomery's etc statistics. The asymptotics does not imply arithmetic.

Comment: Oh-oh, they are too dense! :-))) Taken. Let me say the truth: I don't believe RH and I am not sure that there are unconditional estimates for number of zeta zeros with real part $=1/2$ and imaginary part $<T$ (for any $T$).

Comment: The original question does not refer to $\Re z$, so you can take for any $n$ randomly symmetric $\log n$-set for $\Re\rho$. Of course, this is quite unlikely (so, the original question is irrealistic as well) but your claim "Such a conjecture is false" is true modulo RH.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating your answer Splotchy... Perhaps this conjecture is a too strong claim and hence follows its falsity...

Comment: "I don't believe RH and I am not sure that there are unconditional estimates for number of zeta zeros with real part..."

Great point!!!

I'll wait and do some reading before I accept this answer...

Comment: @Wadim, it's my understanding that it has been known for about 40 years, unconditionally, that at least a third of the zeros up to $T$ have real part 1/2. 

Comment: Thanks, Gerry! This indeed closes the question. After it's already closed. I should stay as far from non-trivial zeta zeros as possible. For safety reasons. :-)